# Determine volume location of a running container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I'm new to Docker and have a question about leaving volume as default. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
                      curl \
                      gnupg2 \
                      git

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I run the container as follows `docker container run -it gcp:1.0`.

The problem comes when I'm trying to inspect the running container:

```
$ sudo docker inspect bfa3a5495364
"Image": "sha256:6edaefc071a94e18d26de68ca90d9fbe11267c32510d1c3683c236d0b4195df7",                                                                                                                                            
"ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bfa3a54953646bee1effccc956c2448fb403083e8faed35afd76a635cd2ccb84/resolv.conf",                                                                                                   
"HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bfa3a54953646bee1effccc956c2448fb403083e8faed35afd76a635cd2ccb84/hostname",                                                                                                        
"HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bfa3a54953646bee1effccc956c2448fb403083e8faed35afd76a635cd2ccb84/hosts",                                                                                                              
"LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bfa3a54953646bee1effccc956c2448fb403083e8faed35afd76a635cd2ccb84/bfa3a54953646bee1effccc956c2448fb403083e8faed35afd76a635cd2ccb84-json.log",                                            
...
"Mounts": [],  
...
```

So since `Mounts` is empty it does not provide any information about the actual volume location which in that case was selected by default. I also tried to print all volumes:

```
$ sudo docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
```

shows no volume.

***QUESTION:*** How to determine volume location that was selected by default?

Comment: there is no volume if you do not mount a volume , example `-v /test:/opt/test/` or just supply a named volume with `-v test`

Comment: @LinPy So I'm going to clone a git repo from interactive docker image run. How to determine the location it is going to be placed?

Comment: that depends on the image, where it replaced all the files in the image to presist data , however some images do not need volumes at all. for example your image does not do anything and can run without volumes

Comment: see the "Where to Store Data" section in https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql for example

Comment: @LinPy _that depends on the image, where it replaced all the files in the image to presist data_ This is what I'm trying to understand. Where is all the data located? For instance I do `touch /root/test`. Where will its location be on a host file system?

Comment: no that will be in the container isolated from the host and will be lost if you delete your container

Comment: @LinPy In case I restart a container by its id that was exited before I will have all the files that I created in the previous session (I just tried it and it worked). So is data bounded to container in some opaque way so they cannot be accessed from the host filesystem

Comment: yes I said "if you delete it" , see my answer below

Comment: You may access files in a container with [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer from the docs:

> By default all files created inside a container are stored on a
>   writable container layer. This means that:
>
> ```
> The data doesn’t persist when that container no longer exists, and it can be difficult to get the data out of the container if another
> ```
>
> process needs it.
>       A container’s writable layer is tightly coupled to the host machine where the container is running. You can’t easily move the data
>   somewhere else.
>       Writing into a container’s writable layer requires a storage driver to manage the filesystem. The storage driver provides a union
>   filesystem, using the Linux kernel. This extra abstraction reduces
>   performance as compared to using data volumes, which write directly to
>   the host filesystem.
>
> Docker has two options for containers to store files in the host
>   machine, so that the files are persisted even after the container
>   stops: volumes, and bind mounts. If you’re running Docker on Linux you
>   can also use a tmpfs mount. If you’re running Docker on Windows you
>   can also use a named pipe.
>
> Keep reading for more information about these two ways of persisting
>   data.

see [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)